# MySQL exit handler ignored

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

An exit handler is being ignored by my stored procedure. I execute the following line:

```
CALL updateTemplate('MyObject', 'NewTemplate');
```

And receive the error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`objects`, CONSTRAINT `Object: Template Foreign Key` FOREIGN KEY (`TemplateId`) REFERENCES `templates` (`TemplateId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Indeed, a constraint does fail, because 'NewTemplate' does not exist in the template table. But why do I not receive the custom error message in the exit handler of the stored procedure below?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateTemplate`(in inObjectId varchar(45), in inTemplateId varchar(45))
BEGIN

    declare exit handler for 1452
    begin
        signal sqlstate '45000' set MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The template identifier is invalid.';
    end;

    UPDATE objects SET TemplateId=inTemplateId WHERE ObjectId=inObjectId;

END
```

For info, I'm running MySQL 5.6.20.

Comment: I think this is due to [a bug that was fixed in 5.7.2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68831).

Comment: Thanks. I'll upgrade and report back.

Answer (score 1):

(Acknowledge GarethD)

This is due to a bug that was fixed in version 5.7.2.

Upgraded to MySQL 5.7.5, and all is now working.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68831