# MySQL Exit Handler for Error 1366 Not Firing

Tags: mysql, error-handling

Using: MySQL 5.6.15

I have an issue with an exit handler not firing on a MySQL function.  I'm not sure if it's related to the issue discussed here: [MySQL exit handler ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293886/mysql-exit-handler-ignored)

I have the following code which takes 2 LAT/LON pairs and finds the distance between the points.  I want to catch anything that is not a decimal (Error 1366) and simply pass back a blank string.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myself`@`%` FUNCTION `DIST_BETWEEN_COORDS`(`lat1` DECIMAL(10,6), `lon1` DECIMAL(10,6), `lat2` DECIMAL(10,6), `lon2` DECIMAL(10,6))
RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Find the distance between 2 sets of coordinates'
BEGIN

DECLARE op VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1366
    BEGIN 
        RETURN '';
    END;

    SET @R := 6371; #Radius of the earth in km
    SET @dLat := RADIANS(lat2-lat1);
    SET @dLon := RADIANS(lon2-lon1);
    SET @a := SIN(@dLat/2) * SIN(@dLat/2) + COS(RADIANS(lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(lat2)) * SIN(@dLon/2) * SIN(@dLon/2);
    SET @c := 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(@a), SQRT(1-@a));
    SET @d := (@R * @c) * 1000; #Distance in meters
    SET @df := @d * 3.28084; #Distance in feet
            IF @df >= 1320 THEN
        SET @dm := @df/5280; #Distance in miles
        SET op = CONCAT(ROUND(@dm,2), " miles");
    ELSE
        SET op = CONCAT(ROUND(@df,2), " feet");
    END IF;

    RETURN op;

END
```

The function itself works great, but the EXIT handler never fires, even if I send a blank or text string to the function for one of the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The exit handler is not fired because the error is not raised. If you try to insert a non integer value in an integer column, the handler would be fired.

Additionally, the parameters are DECIMAL(10, 6). Any error would be raised before the function is called.

You can pass your parameters as VARCHAR or CHAR and validate them yourself if needed.

Comment: When I run the function with an non-numeric value I get: /* SQL Error (1366): Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'lon2' at row 1 */